# Given an array of integer numbers, sum this number and all numbers that after it

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, reduce

At the end I get numbers, how to convert it to array?

Example:

Input: 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, -2

Output: [(13, 9, 4, 3, 1, -2)];

```js
function sumNumbers(numbersList) {
  const data = numbersList.forEach((item, index) => {
    const output = numbersList.reduce(
      (acc, c, i) => (index !== i ? (acc += c) : c),
      0
    );
    console.log(result);

    return output;
  });
  return data;
}

sumNumbers([4, 5, 1, 2, 3, -2]);
```

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't return anything and therefor "ignores" `return main`

Answer (score 2):

Consider replacing the [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (since we want the value returned)

```js
function sumNumbers(numbersList) {
  const main = numbersList.map((item, index) => {
    const result = numbersList.reduce(
      (acc, c, i) => (index !== i ? (acc += c) : c),
      0
    );

    return result;
  });
  return main;
}

console.log(sumNumbers([4, 5, 1, 2, 3, -2]))
```

---

**Explanation:**

`.forEach` returns undefined ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value))

while `.map` returns "A new array with each element being the result of the callback function." ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#return_value))

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your answer, it really helped me a lot! I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

The response given by @tibebes-m,  an other approach (which reduces complexity) is to iterate back the array backwards, and use only a reduce function (no map)

```js
const sumNumbers = (list) => list
  .reverse()
  .reduce((acc, next, index) => {
      acc.unshift(next + (acc[0] || 0));
      return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(sumNumbers([4, 5, 1, 2, 3, -2]));
```